# Conditional join between a list and a datatable on linq

Tags: c#, linq, join

This is my first try on Linq. I managed to join a list and a dataset but join part still needs a fine tuning. Linq codepiece is below.

```
    DataTable dt = CacheManager.Gtipler.Tables[0];
    List<TescilInfo> GtiplerList = new List<TescilInfo>();

    //a foreach loop here to populate the list

    var result = from db in dt.AsEnumerable()
                 join tescil in GtiplerList on db.Field<string>("Kod") equals tescil.GtipNo
                 select db.Field<string>("AdiTR");
```

What I need to do is to check if tescil.GtipNo (an 8 character string) ends with 00 it should be diminished into a 6 character string and used in join like that.
i.e;

if it is 12345600 it will be used as 123456.

Is there a way to do this in a Linq query? If yes, how?

Comment: Did You find your answer ?

Comment: My supervisor just told me to overcome this by using (and) and (or) operators.

Comment: Can you paste this "overcomed" solution ? Would like to see and compare performance of it :)

Comment: Ok so paste it when you'll finish if You have no problem about that :). I gave You working solution and I bet a solution with ands/ors can't be better than this(i'm not saying mine is the best one, just not the worst one), remember SuperVisors aren't always right. :)

Comment: I have no idea how can I use those operators on this scenario :)

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You could also use where operator to eliminate those withou 00 at the end and later join on tescil.GtipNo.Substring(0,6)

Comment: I gave You second solution. Those are two solution I can imagine that it make sense

Comment: Go check 3rd answer, i think this is what You were looking for

Answer (score 2):

I think that You're looking for let statement. Try this:

```
var result = from db in dt.AsEnumerable()
             let temp = GtiplerList.Where(x => x.GtipNo.EndsWith("00")) // i assume GtipNo is a string already so no need to ToString() it
             join tescil in temp on db.Field<string>("Kod") equals tescil.GtipNo.Substring(0,6) // substring to get first 6 characters
             select db.Field<string>("AdiTR");
```

EDIT. Solution 2 without let operator:

```
var result = from db in dt.AsEnumerable()
             join tescil in temp on db.Field<string>("Kod") equals tescil.GtipNo
             where tescil.GtipNo.Substring(6,2) == "00"
             select db.Field<string>("AdiTR");
```

EDIT. 2 - after chat i understand what You need.

To perform such join you just need to change part after equals operator, see below:

```
var result = from db in dt.AsEnumerable()
             join tescil in GtiplerList on db.Field<string>("Kod") equals (tescil.GtipNo.EndsWith("00") ? x.Substring(0, 6) : x)
             select db.Field<string>("AdiTR");
```

So above code will set right side of equals operator to correct value depending on whether GtipNo ends with 00 or not.

Comment: I haven't tried this but edit part looks like it joins only those which end as "00". Currently those which end as "00" are not joining but I need them to join along with all others.

Comment: "What I need to do is to check if tescil.GtipNo (an 8 character string) ends with 00 it should be diminished into a 6 character string and used in join" - which part I did not understand ?

Comment: For example I have 42 records at the hand now. 14 of them end with 00 so only 28 of 42 make it through the join. I need whole 42 of them to join.

Comment: Ok but what if record doesn't end with 00 ?

Comment: Then it's ok to join it as 8 characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91391/discussion-between-ege-bayrak-and-majkelodev).

Answer (score 0):

String.TrimEnd() will remove all trailing occurrences of a given character ('0' in this case) and return a new, trimmed string.  You can use this method in your 'join... on...' statement.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx

To instead only remove two trailing zeroes (instead of one, three, or more), you will need more sophistication as in the other answer.

Comment: It's just a partial answer. Doesn't solve all OP's problems - just one.

Comment: there might be occurences where there are four or more  0's but only last two should be removed. Like 12340000 should be turned into 123400.

Comment: @EgeBayrak did You try my solution ?